# Unexpected less gzip compression with -9

Tags: compression, gzip, disk-image

I do have a USB mass storage device of 4GB, in which I had created two partition, both are of ext4.
First partition is 1.5G and another one is 2.5G

First partition is almost full while second one is empty.

When I take `dd` of this device, then resultant dd file size is as expected i.e. 4GB.  Now, when I `gzip --best` to this file, then I am expecting resultant `gz` file size must be aroung 1.4GB at the max. But practically, size remains aprrox. 2.5 GB.

The value, which I'm assuming, is wrong OR I miscalculated something ??

commands I had used are as:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=USB.dd
gzip --best USB.dd
```

Comment: Examine your disk dump prior to gzip'ing.  Just because a portion of the disk is "empty" from your perspective, does not mean it is filled with an easily compressible pattern, like uniform 0x00.

Comment: Are you expecting me to `shred` the second partition before the above mentioned exercise ?

Comment: If you want to ensure the second partition is compressible, yes, you could do something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=${partition_to_clear}` or `shred -z`